# Double dispatch using visitor pattern in Java

Tags: java, interface, implements, visitor-pattern, double-dispatch

I have this architecture:
[image: architecture Visitor pattern]

In `XMLFormulaFormatter`, I need the value of instances of `Constant` (instances which are created in my Main class).

I have this method in the `Constant` class:

```
public double asValue() { return value ; }
```

I have tried this code in `XMLFormulaFormatter` class:

```
@Override
     public String visit(Constant constant){ 
        latexConstant = constant.asValue() ;
        return "";
        }
```

But of course it does not give me the what I am looking at as I want to get the value of a specific instance of `Constant`...

I have also tried in the `format()` method of `XMLFormulaFormatter`:

```
@Override
    public String format(Formula format){ format.accept(this);
    if (format instanceof Constant){
        latexConstant= format.asValue();
        return "";
        }
```

But same result, as expected.

Any thoughts on how to get the value of a specific instance of `Constant`?

Thanks!

Comment: The architecture seems reasonable. In the code snippets it is odd to return an empty String; but I am not sure what the problem is. What is happening in the code and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect from the code in XMLFormulaFormatter is to retrieve calculations of sum and product from those classes (which I have done), but I also need to display the value of the constants used to make those calculations and this is the problem that I have: I don t know how to retrieve them (PS: The return "" is just a placeholder for the time being)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it, I need a getter in `AbstractVariadicOperator`